# Shopware 6 - Order Price Recalculation Error in Administration

Tags: shopware, shopware6

While trying to add a credit note position or a new position to an order through the administration (Shopware v.6.5.3.1), I get price recalculation errors such as Warning: Undefined array key "018943b816a372a880d4d9e44c198f6d" where the binary-value corresponds to the product-id of the line item (see screenshot).
I have noticed that the problem occurs only on orders featuring imported variant products from shopware 5 (via shopware migration tool). Orders with new products that have been inserted through the admin can be recalculated properly.
Apparently shopware has problem connecting the dots on some of the ordered products, that he uses to recalculate.
[Error triggered by symfony compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NddV.jpg)
[Error triggered on Admin Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6OHA.jpg)

I was analyzing and comparing the db product tables of imported products and newly via admin inserted products but could not find any difference or anomalies on the data of the imported products.
I checked the order tables including order delivery positions and order line items but these look fine.
I also checked the variable outputs during the checkout process with variabe dump but there again, could not find any difference between imported products and newly via admin inserted products.
Generally the imported products are displayed and can be ordered without errors in the frontend.

Did someone already have this issue? Could this be a data format issue within the database?

Thanks for your ideas!
Greets
Cedric